# Swift ArraySlice with zero-based index

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm running into a performance bottleneck with Vapor's multi-part parser, when copying an ArraySlice into a new Array.

Presumably the copying is done to allow accessing the slice's first byte at index zero in other parts of the framework.

Giving the huge penalty for copying a few bytes, isn't there a way in Swift to create a subarray without copying who's first index starts at zero, so it can be passed to other components without needing to translate indices?

[image]

Source: https://github.com/vapor/multipart/blob/master/Sources/Multipart/Parser.swift

Comment: Please post your code directly, not just in a screenshot.

Comment: As for the contents of the screenshot, I would expect that the performance hit is from making the `Array` copy, not necessarily the slice. If you change your `buffer` property to allow it to contain a slice instead of hard-coding it to an `Array` and requiring the copy each time, you'll likely see much better performance.

Comment: Also: you shouldn't use `buffer.count` in a range. Use one of these three options instead: `buffer[pos...]`, `buffer[pos..<buffer.endIndex]`, or `buffer.suffix(from: pos)`.

Comment: Should have added that the code is from the offical Vapor repo: https://github.com/vapor/multipart/blob/master/Sources/Multipart/Parser.swift

Comment: I'm not familiar with that framework or how it's supposed to work, but if it's causing legitimate performance problems by using copies where slices would be sufficient, you might want to file a report on their Issues page to let them know (or submit a patch fixing it).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try coming up with a patch. Just thought there would be easier way than using ArraySlices…